# Prove $ \ (A^c \cup B^c) - A = A^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Prove $ \ (A^c \cup B^c) - A = A^c$

My attempt:

Let $ x \in (A^c \cup B^c) - A \implies x \in A^c \cup B^c$ and $x \notin A \implies (x\in A^c$ or $ \ x\in B^c)$ and $ x \notin A \implies (x \in A^c$ and $x \notin A)$ or $ ( x\in B^c$ and $ x \notin A) \implies x\notin A \implies x \in A^c$, either way.

Let $ \ x\in A^c \implies x \in (A^c\cup B^c)$ and $\ x\in A^c \implies x \in (A^c\cup B^c) \ and \ x\notin A \implies x \in \ (A^c \cup B^c) - A$

I have to prove this question using set containment. I am not quite sure if my logic is correct.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me

Comment: The first part of the proof is fine, but too long: you can go directly from "$x\in A^c\cup B^c$ and $x\notin A$" to "$x\notin A$" and skip the two extra steps.

Comment: It is correct.☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic looks fine to me. There are a few shortcuts you could take, though. Note, for instance, that $x \in A^c \cup B^c$ and $x \notin A\implies x\notin A$, which allows you to skip a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Rewrite your expression like $(A \cap B)^{c} -A = A^{c}$, using Demorgan 's law now it is easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Haha:

Let $A,B,C \subset X$.

$C - A = C \cap A^c$.

Set $C : = (A^c \cup B^c)$ , then

$C - A = C \cap A^c = $

$(A^c \cup B^c) \cap A^c =$

$(A^c \cap A^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) =$

$A^c \cup (A^c \cap B^c) = A^c$.